# my postgreSQL doesn't give me password option when installing

Tags: postgresql

postgreSQL application doesn't ask me for a password when installing it to my machine. I don't know if that is why none of password i entered in my terminal is being rejected.

Please how do i solve this ?

Comment: How do you install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed PostgreSQL on a modern version of Linux from the repositories supplied by Canonical, you do not set a password. Instead, you will need to switch to the `postgres` user account, *then* connect.

Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (or connect to the server via SSH)
1. Switch to the `postgres` user account:

   ```
   sudo -i -u postgres
   ```
2. Access PostgreSQL:

   ```
   psql
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** You will be connected as a superadmin, which will give you the opportunity to create accounts that can be used by applications and/or people.</sup>

That's all there is to it